# How not to display posts from a certain category?

Tags: categories, pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclude Category From Home Page, Display Posts on It's Own Page?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41820/exclude-category-from-home-page-display-posts-on-its-own-page)

This is what I want to do:

1. I don't want posts from a certain category to show up in my blog. ie, category: shop
2. Instead I want to display them on a separate page not category archive.

instead of only posts from a certain category to show I want a single category not to show on main blog.

how do I do it?

Comment: I've just posted [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56479/9364) to that question, which answers this question also. Voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: where do I put that code snippet?

Comment: Inside a plug-in or `functions.php`.